# Docker Desktop not working on macOS after update

Tags: docker, macos

I just updated to macOS Monterey 12.4, and now Docker Desktop is not working at all. It was working fine before.

I've tried many things to troubleshoot this with no success:

1. Clicking any of the following troubleshooting buttons does nothing. It's unresponsive and shows no signs of success or failure:

[image]

2. Reinstalling `docker` with `brew` doesn't work:

```bash
brew uninstall --cask docker
brew install --cask docker
```

3. Uninstalling the app from Brew, and then installing the [Apple Silicon .dmg from Docker's website](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/) didn't work.
4. Removing the app's files and then reinstalling via step #2 or #3 didn't work:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.docker
rm -rf ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.electron.docker-frontend.savedState
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.electron.docker-frontend.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/com.docker.docker.plist
rm -rf ~/Library/Group\ Containers/group.com.docker/
rm -rf ~/Library/Cookies/com.docker.docker.binarycookies
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.docker.docker
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Docker\ Desktop/
```

5. Restarting my Mac doesn't work.
6. Restarting the Docker app doesn't work.
7. Killing all Docker processes with the Activity Monitor doesn't work.
8. Deleting the app from `/Applications` and then reinstalling it doesn't work.

Upon further inspection, I've been getting the following error:

```bash
~ docker ps
Error response from daemon: dial unix /Users/daniel/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/docker.raw.sock: connect: no such file or directory
```

This error has stayed the same no matter what I've tried. I'm completely baffled.

### Environment

- macOS Monterey 12.4
- Mac mini (M1, 2020)
- Chip: Apple M1
- Memory: 16GB

Comment: I just reported this as an issue on GitHub. I suspect it's a bug: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6331

Answer (score -3):

Just get the official package from https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/mac-install/